# strfry(char *__string) returns int?

Tags: c

So I'm new to C and I'm playing around with functions in the GNU C Library when I come across https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/strfry.html#strfry

Intrigued, I wrote a little tester program:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <string.h>
3 
4 main ()
5 {
6     char *str = "test123abc";
7     char *other;
8 
9     other = strfry(str);
10    printf("%s\n", other);
11     return 0;
12 }
```

`gcc test.c` outputs `test.c:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Why?

`/usr/include/string.h` has the following entry:

`extern char *strfry (char *__string) __THROW __nonnull ((1));`

How can a `char *function(...)` return `int`?

Thanks

Comment: When you compile, you should probably add the `-Wall` flag. That would help you get additional warnings that could help you determine your problem.

Comment: I really like Ulrich Drepper's comment on strfry() here: http://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4403

Comment: Just check the man page to find out the full prototype - you don't need to search through include files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `strfry` is a GNU extension, you need to [`#define _GNU_SOURCE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-g_t_005fGNU_005fSOURCE-51) to use it. If you fail to provide that `#define`, the declaration will not be visible and the compiler will automatically assume that the function returns `int`.

A related problem, as pointed out by perreal, is that it is undefined behavior to modify a literal string. Once you make the declaration of `strfry` visible to the compiler, this will be duly reported.

Do note that the `strfry` function and its cousin [`memfrob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Trivial-Encryption.html) are not entirely serious and are rarely used in production.

Comment: OK so why do `strcmp(...)` and others work without `#define _GNU_SOURCE`?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 - Because `strcmp` is in the language spec, it isn't a GNU extension.

Comment: @asveikau how do I tell the difference?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 because GNU C, is *not* Standard C.  It's an extension, that isn't compiled in normally.  It also invades the reserved namespace of str* from standard C.  Look at man pages (or preferably the C standard) to find out what functions are standard.

Comment: @JB0x2D1 `strcmp` is defined by the relevant standards, such as C89, C99, and POSIX. As explained [in the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#index-g_t_005fGNU_005fSOURCE-51): "If you don't specify the ‘-ansi’ option to GCC and don't define any of these macros explicitly, the effect is the same as defining _POSIX_C_SOURCE to 2 and _POSIX_SOURCE, _SVID_SOURCE, and _BSD_SOURCE to 1."

Comment: @JB0x2D1 You can check the man page, which typically documents which standard(s) the functions conform to. Another clue is that the function is undeclared unless you define `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: OK so is Standard C == ANSI C == ISO C?  When I started looking through the GNU.org web pages on the GNU C Library, I thought that was the standard.  Thank you for correcting me.  What resource should I be looking at?

Comment: I like the [POSIX.1-2008 site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for checking C functions (both Standard and POSIX). `strfry()`, for example, is not documented at that site.

Comment: @JB0x2D1 Yes, all those three refer to [standard C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C), accepted in the same form by American and international standardization bodies. POSIX, on the other hand, is a superset of the C standard that defines the implementation of modern Unix systems. For example, `memcpy` is C, `sleep` is POSIX, and `strfry` is neither.

Comment: I think http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/ is what I was looking for all along.  It gives an overview of the standard C library.

Answer (score 4):

To have `strfry` available, you need

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

otherwise the prototype is not exposed and the implicit declaration is assumed to return an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't have a prototype in scope for `strfry()` and the compiler assumes it returns an `int`. When it wants to assign that int to a `char*` it complains with the message you specify.

According to my man pages, you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the very top of your source code, especially before standard #includes

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
/* rest of your program */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a literal string:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
  char *str = "test123abc";
  char other[256];
  strcpy(other, str);
  strfry(other);
  printf("%s\n", other);
  return 0;
}
```